# Why requireJs wouldn't load defined dependency modules?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am having problem while using Require.js to load dependencies for my module. Basically I have following module in which I define extension of Backbone Model.

```
define(["models/services/ProjectServices"],

    function (ProjectServices) {

        var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

             sample: function () {
             var servicesFromDependency = ProjectServices; //undefined
             var projectServices = window.require.s.contexts._.defined["models/services/ProjectServices"]; //defined and Ok
             }
         });
        return SomeModel;
    }
);
```

In this module I want to use already defined ProjectServices module. In order to do that I add it as a dependency. The thing is that within defined sample function ProjectServices is showing as undefined. But if I look directly into require defined modules it is showing there correctly and I can use it (although I do not want as I don't like to hack it this way). To add more context, I am also using this ProjectServices dependency on other module and there it is loaded properly through define function.

Any suggestions on why module would not be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside a module:

```
var ProjectServices = require('models/services/ProjectServices');
```

I think in many situations, there is no need for window global assignment and I try to avoid while using requirjs.

Comment: As it behaves like circular dependency, I would take this as correct answer as it is also suggested by requirejs docs in such cases

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can come up with is a possible circular reference, meaning that two modules require each other (which should not be the case).

As you say that the require works well in other modules, it should not be due to a missing return statement in the required module, or a wrong path. (You might check this anyway).

Comment: thnaks for suggestion, I did not found a circular dependence per se but the way it behaves may suggest that it was evaluated by require like circular dependency